# Importing a .wav file in c# and extracting the signal an array of doubles

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point, double, wav

I'm doing a project on audio signal processing and I need to import a wav file in c# and extract an array of doubles or floats that contains the signal data. Most of the tutorials for audio libraries I've found don't seem to do stuff this low-level. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/ libsndfile is a nice C library, if you can choose your language.

Comment: Use NAudio, WaveStream class.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/PlayWavFiles.aspx
this site helped me, but the .exe file became very large due to the imported wav files. So sending the project via email will be a problem. :)
I hope I'm not too late; you posted this quite a while ago...

Comment: -1: It just play wav file using `System.Media.SoundPlayer`. Cannot get wav array using it!